# create json from input type array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, javascript-objects

On submitting a form I am getting a form object and making object. Now situation is I have input type array, for example I have input type "Task links" on click plus sign each time I am adding new input type text up to five. 
It could be three, two, five or in case I increase up to twenty in future, how I will handle it in javascript to make object, see the code below

[See screenshot for better understanding](http://prntscr.com/h8n55g)

```
<input type="text" name="arr[]">
<input type="text" name="arr[]">

function submit_task_form (form_obj) {

    var get_form = document.getElementById(form_obj);

    var form_data = {};
    for(var i=0; i<get_form.length; i++) {
        form_data.task_link = get_form[i];
    }
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: oh ya thats right just object I mean

Comment: thank you for correcting me

Comment: I just fix it above

Comment: Are you sure you want an object rather than an array. If it's an object you want, what are the keys because all you're doing at the moment is replacing `task_link` in the object each time with the link from the next input in the iteration.

Comment: Ya I know I don't want to replace the previous one I want a new key with new value if there is

Comment: any solution you suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear whether you need an object or an array, so here's a couple of examples that show both. These examples are in ES6. I can rewrite them in ES5 if you're not familiar with the syntax.

Both examples assume that there is a class called `link` on the input elements (to differentiate them from any other inputs you might have).

```
<input class="link" value="sdfs" />
```

1) Array **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/11ta1cbv/4/)**

Pick up the inputs and iterate over them with `map`:

```
function getLinks() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
  return [...links].map(link => link.value);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
[ "sdfs", "34", "min", "987" ]
```

ES5 syntax **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/11ta1cbv/4/#update)**

```
function getLinks() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    arr.push(links[i].value);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

2) Object **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/11ta1cbv/6/)**

This utilises a data-id attribute as the key for the link values.

```
<input class="link" data-id="1" value="sdfs" />
```

This time we create an object with `reduce` instead.

```
function getLinks() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
  return [...links].reduce((obj, link) => {
    const id = link.dataset.id;
    obj[id] = link.value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
}
```

OUTPUT

```
{
  1: "sdfs"
  2: "34"
  3: "min"
  4: "987"
}
```

ES5 Syntax **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/11ta1cbv/7/)**

```
function getLinks() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    let id = links[i].dataset.id;
    obj[id] = links[i].value;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: I didnt understand the syntax

Comment: I need an object to pass it to php via ajax at the end

Comment: data: {action: "submit_task_form_with_ajax", form_data: form_data},

Comment: or I think I can assign an array of input types to the key of object

Comment: I don't know, any suggestion :)

Comment: Dear Andy is this syntax javascript, I didn't understand const, let and query Selector()

Comment: I've added the ES5 syntax that you're probably more familiar with. You can build your own AJAX object when you decide what you want your `form_data` to be.

Comment: `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are just different methods of getting at DOM elements, very similar to how jQuery works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll